# Connecting a SQL Server View in MS Access with VBA

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-access, odbc

I have created a View in SQL Server (`dbo.ViewMySQL`) and now want to query it from MS Access with ADO, the connection string looks like:

```
    cs = "Driver={SQL Server};"
    cs = cs & "Server=IP,port;"
    cs = cs & "Database=database_name;"

con.Open cs, "user", "password"
```

I tried the following SQL-Statements:

```
strQry = "select * from dbo_ViewMySQL"
strQry = "select * from viewMySQL"
strQry = "select * from [dbo].[viewMySQL]"
strQry = "select * from [db-name].[dbo].[viewMySQL]"
```

The error message says that the object-name is invalid

> Laufzeitffehler '-2147217865 (80040e37)': [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server
>   Driver][SQL Server] Ungültiger Objektname 'dbo_ViewMySQL'

for `strQry = "select * from tbl_Test"` and other tables it works, but not for the view, why is that?

Thank you

Comment: what is your table called on the sql server?

Comment: In which schema is the view located?  try  `"select * from [schemaName].[ViewName]"`

Comment: Schema is dbo - `strQry = "select * from [dbo].[ViewMySQL]"`doesn't work

Comment: 1. Is the error message the same for `[dbo].[viewMySQL]` ?  -- 2. Are you sure the user has access rights to the view (i.e. GRANT SELECT) ?

Comment: I tried: `GRANT SELECT ON [ViewMySQL] TO [MyUsername]` -  the error remains the same: Invalid object name

Comment: Make sure the view itself is linked in Access.  When you do this, it will likely change the linked view in Access to dbo_ViewMySQL, but you can change this by renaming the linked view the same way you'd rename any other Access object.

Comment: @JohnnyBones: as I understand it (I never use ADO), OP directly connects to SQL Server, as in a Pass-Through query, so linking the view in Access shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: Linking via the ODBC-Database in database tools directly works, but I can't imagine why this souldn't work in vba

Comment: Has anyone found an answer on this yet?